# Kendo Grid Virtualization of Lots of Data with Filters?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using Kendo UI grid in a project. The grid needs to load data from backend. The code works fine until when the data size is huge.

After some research, it seems we can use Virtualization to solve this issue:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-remote-data

However, I noticed that, when uses virtualization, the grid usually does not have filter options. What if the grid has filter options, does the virtualization still work?

I checked the example in the above link, it seems it will not work if the filters are added. Is this true? or, there is a way to get around this.

Thanks